# What does ((void (*) ())shellcode) () do, where shellcode is an unsigned char array?

Tags: exploit, shellcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned char random[] = //randomness

unsigned char shellcode[] = //shellcode in hex

int main(void)
{

((void (*) ())shellcode) ();

}
```

What does ((void (*) ())shellcode) (); do?

Comment: I don't think this is the proper place to ask this. Stackoverflow may suit better. Anyway it just takes the hex encoded shellcode and executes it. The shellcode is just some assembly code, you can see the assembly using tools like radare2 or [an online shellcode disassembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2). It's done that way to avoid compiler optimizations

Answer (score 1):

Use objdump and gdb and it becomes pretty apparent what's going on with that ridiculous piece of code.

A program is a sequence of binary. An equivalent representation for the binary that the processor executes are hex values. The hex representation is entirely equivalent, simply another representation.  So when a bunch of hex values are put into the address that shellcode lives at, when an instruction says to point at the start of it then the comp does and starts processing the binary at that address.

Look in gdb to see what the fancy function does.

```
$gdb -q holac
....
   0x56555560 <+0>: lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0x56555564 <+4>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x56555567 <+7>: pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   0x5655556a <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x5655556b <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x5655556d <+13>:    push   %ecx
   0x5655556e <+14>:    sub    $0x4,%esp
   0x56555571 <+17>:    call   0x56555591 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x56555576 <+22>:    add    $0x1a62,%eax
   0x5655557b <+27>:    lea    0x30(%eax),%eax
=> 0x56555581 <+33>:    call   *%eax
   0x56555583 <+35>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x56555588 <+40>:    add    $0x4,%esp
   0x5655558b <+43>:    pop    %ecx
   0x5655558c <+44>:    pop    %ebp
   0x5655558d <+45>:    lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
   0x56555590 <+48>:    ret  

(gdb) print/x $eax
$1 = 0x56557008
```

Here we see my very malicious looking shellcode

```
(gdb) x/20x $eax
0x56557008 <shellcode>: 0xddccbbaa  0xbbeeeeff  0xbbbbbbaa  0x00000000
0x56557018: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x56557028: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x56557038: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x56557048: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

See, it's going to call the value that eax points at when it gets to 0x56555581, which just means to move the instruction pointer to the address eax contains. It doesn't know you plugged instructions at that address directly, and it doesn't care where the instructions came from, it will go merrily along executing.

```
(gdb) print/x $eip     //breaked at the call, eip still points to call
$2 = 0x56555581
(gdb) stepi
0x56557008 in shellcode ()
(gdb) print/x $eip     //now eip (instruction pointer) points to start of shellcode
$3 = 0x56557008
```